# Declaring arrow functions as variables

Tags: ecmascript-6

In a previous project using webpack and babel writing es2015 I was able to declare an arrow function with a name like this:

```
x = () => console.log("test");
```

Using a real function it would look like this:

```
fetch = () => {
      fetch(`https://www.data.com`)
      .then(response => response.json() {
        console.log(response);
      })}
```

However when trying to use this code in a browserify and gulp configuration I get the error

> Unexpected token, expected ,

Can you tell me why this code only works when I use webpack?

Comment: Because Webpack was configured to use Babel, and Browserify wasn't? If you have problems with Gulp and Browserify, please, specify how they are configured. The question in its current state is off-topic, it is not possible to answer it.

Comment: They should be configured identically using the same .babelrc file

 `"presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"]´

I am already using imports and exports so I thought this would mean that gulp and browserify is already configured to use es 2015

Comment: They should. But are they? Please, provide their configurations.

Comment: What node version are you using? http://node.green/#ES2015-functions-arrow-functions

Comment: `response => response.json() { }` what's going on here? Looks like a syntax error to my eye.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code. `response => response.json() { }` is invalid JS.

To log the response:

```
fetch('https://www.data.com')
  .then(response => console.log(response))
```

To convert the response to JSON before logging it:

```
fetch('https://www.data.com')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```